# How to view last created items in Liferay database

Tags: mysql, liferay, liferay-7

My program uses Liferay services to create items, such as web content items.

How to see the latest created items in the database?

I can't rely on `createDate` or `modifiedDate` as I set these dynamically to various dates in the past (migrating content from legacy Domino).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not run a cluster, use this solution (cluster machines do not necessarily allocate ids strictly sequentially, but cache blocks of ids st once. Thanks to Olaf Kock for the tip!):

Connect to your database (using MySQL Workbench for instance).

Run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM JournalArticle order by convert(`articleId`, decimal) desc;
```

That example is for web content. For other types of data, replace `JournalArticle` and `articleId` as appropriate. For instance for a layout write `Layout` and `plid`. Check the schema for other types.

Explanation: Item identifiers are incremental integers (*at least in Liferay 7, beware that it might change in the future*). This functionality is provided by the CounterService (`CounterService.increment(entityClazz)`). Despite being integer, they are stored as `varchar`, so you have to convert them to `decimal` before sorting.

Comment: This is only true if you do not run a cluster. Cluster machines do not necessarily allocate ids strictly sequentially, but cache blocks of ids st once.

Comment: @OlafKock: Thanks, very informative! I added your info to the body of the answer. I don't use a cluster on my current project, but if you know any convenient solution that also works in a cluster a new answer would be very welcome :-)